# VPN p2s has connected but not able to access resources

Tags: azure-vpn

I got VM on azure with windows2012. And then setup the P2S VPN and has connected but can not access any resources of VM from my laptop say files.
After the VPN connection its receiving the IP of the VPN range. The ping is also working from my local network to VPN gateway and VM after VPN has connected.
Do I have to create any End point for this purpose.

Comment: can you put me in the right direction

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming, try http://superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

bsl2, you can post your question on the MSDN Azure Networking forum (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/home?forum=WAVirtualMachinesVirtualNetwork) and Azure Support will help.